# Weird symbols when reading data from a file?

Tags: c++, arrays, text, output

I have a program that is meant to take data from 2 separate text files, place them in arrays, compare them to each other, and output certain results. However, when I read the data from the files and try to display the data, I get a lot of weird symbols before it finally displays all the data in the text files. Here is the code.

```
// Ch07-Exam Grader.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

//Libraries
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Prototypes
void initialization(void);
void proccess(void);
void eoj(void);
void writeIt(void);
void readIt(void);
void calculate(void);

//Global Variables
ifstream student;
ifstream correct;


int main()
{
initialization();

return 0;
}

//This function opens the files and calls the function to send the data into the array
void initialization (void){
correct.open("CorrectAnswers.txt");
readIt();

student.open("StudentAnswers.txt");
readIt();

}
void proccess (char c[], char s[], int length){

int correctCount = 0;
int incorrectCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i< length; i++){
    if (s[i] == c[i]){
        correctCount = correctCount + 1;
    } else {
        incorrectCount = incorrectCount + 1;
    }
}

}
void eoj (void){

}
void writeIt (void){

}

//This function will take the data and place it into seperate arrays
void readIt (void){
char studentArray[20]; //Array to hold the student answers
char correctArray[20]; //Array to hold the correct answers

//Loops to place data to seperate arrays
for (int i = 0; !correct.eof(); i++){
    correct >> correctArray[i];
}
for (int j = 0; !student.eof(); j++){
    student >> studentArray[j];
}
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    cout << studentArray[i] <<endl;
}
proccess(correctArray, studentArray, 20);

}
void calculate (void){

}
```

And this is the result:

[image: weird output]

Only the letters are a part of the text file.

Comment: Show at least a part of the input files.... And please, compile with all warnings and learn to use the debugger.

Comment: `readIt()` reads from both `correct` and `student`, but you're calling it before you open `student`.

Comment: What a simple mistake. Thanks a lot for the help. I've got it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you call readIt() twice in initialization() function? It looks like readIt() expects that both files are open, but you open first file, call readIt(), open second file, call readIt() again. May be the reason of the problem in this defect?